# "Read timed out" error when uploading large file from Jenkins to Nexus artifact repository

Tags: docker, jenkins, nexus

I have a series of large files that need to be uploaded to a Nexus artifact repository using the Nexus Artifact Uploader plugin in Jenkins. I have many jobs built that use this plugin and correctly upload the files to Nexus. Unfortunately, I am seeing that there is a ~2.5GB file size limit after which the Jenkins job fails with error "Read timed out". When I use a curl command to push the artifacts directly to the Nexus repo, it does not fail. This makes me believe that the timeout is being applied by Jenkins or possibly the Docker container that Jenkins is running on. I have attached the log below. Does anyone here have any suggestions about how I could solve this timeout error?

```
09:54:28 Uploading artifact (artifact file).zip started....
09:54:28 GroupId: data
09:54:28 ArtifactId: (artifact name)
09:54:28 Classifier: 
09:54:28 Type: zip
09:54:28 Version: 0.0.1
09:54:28 File: (artifact file).zip
09:54:28 Repository:(repository name)
09:54:28 Uploading: https://(nexus location)/repository/(repo name)/data/(artifact name)/0.0.1/(artifact name)-0.0.1.zip
09:54:50 10 % completed (902 MB / 9.0 GB).
09:55:12 20 % completed (1.8 GB / 9.0 GB).
09:56:20 Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact data:(artifact name):zip:0.0.1 from/to (repo name) (https://(nexus location)/repository/repo name): Read timed out
09:56:20 ERROR: Uploading file (artifact file).zip failed.
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to  set jvm parameter `-Dmaven.wagon.rto` e.g.:

```
"-Dmaven.wagon.rto=1800000"
```

or set pom.xml properties

```
<maven.wagon.rto>1800000</maven.wagon.rto>
```

for more details follow this link https://maven.apache.org/wagon/wagon-providers/wagon-http/